# C++ OpenGL Pong ball moving too fast

Tags: c++, opengl, timer, pong

Im trying to create a simple pong game in C++ using opengl. I have the borders displaying on the screen, the paddles, the ball, and all of them move, so that's great! The problem is that the ball moves lightning fast even at one pixel of speed.

Im updating it's position in a call-back function called init which I then pass into glutIdleFunc like so: `glutIdleFunc(idle);`

the idle function is as follows:

```
void idle(){
    ball.moveLeft();

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

essentially im just having it move left by one pixel but, I guess that idle gets called a lot so it moves lightning fast. How do I fix this error?

If there's more information you need just ask!

Comment: Time a very important aspect in any simulation. Take into account the time that has passed by between two frames.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `glut`, but something called `IdleFunc` doesn't seem like the place to put graphics updates to me!

Comment: Use `glutTimerFunc`. GLUT timers only fire once, so don't forget to set it up in the callback again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a GLUT timer to kick your `display()` callback every 16 milliseconds:

```
void timer( int extra )
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc( 16, timer, 0 );
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( ... );
    glutInitWindowSize( ... );
    glutCreateWindow( ... );
    ...
    glutTimerFunc( 0, timer, 0 );
    ...
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But im updating where it updates it's position in the idle function. Then that calls glutPostRedisplay(); which calls display so don't we need to limit the speed of the idle function?

Comment: Don't use the idle function, just use the timer.

Comment: So also add the ball.moveLeft() into the timer function?

Comment: Sweet, to get it to move faster, do I switch the speed of it, or decrease the millisecond wait of the timer?

Comment: Keep the 16ms/frame constant and increase the units/frame that your objects move.

Comment: Note that glutTimerFunc does not guarantee that it will do the callback exactly every 16ms.  You should find out the exact time to avoid surprises when your frame rate varies.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link I found to a blog that talks about how to get the time in glut to display frames per second.

http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/frames-per-second/

You need to decide what the velocity of your ball is in pixels/second.  Then multiply that velocity by the number of seconds that have elapsed between your last update & the current update.  According to the blog, you can get this via glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME).  If that doesn't work, google for how to find the current time in milliseconds on your platform.

Hope this helps.